# Cambodian currency symbol is not being displayed properly

Tags: android, unicode, textview, currency, android-fonts

I am trying to display the Cambodian currency symbol (៛) in Android

[image: Cambodian currency symbol]

My Android code is

`tvDetailDescription.setText("៛"); //with string
 tvDetailDescription.setText("\u17DB"); //with unicode`

But it is displaying as below:

[image]

I do not know why this happeing.

Answer (score 0):

The default Android font Roboto does not include the Cambodian currency symbol. See [here](http://www.fontspace.com/google/roboto/21071/charmap) for an overview of supported characters. Use a custom font to display the symbol properly. Add the font to your `assets/fonts`-folder and use it like this:

```
    Typeface DosisRegular = Typeface.createFromAsset(mContext.getAssets(), "fonts/Dosis-Regular.otf");
    mDetailDescription.setTypeface(DosisRegular);
```

Comment: Thanks [Bill S.](http://stackoverflow.com/users/7819508/bill-s) I am using the custom font but I want to know why it is mapping to the wrong character.

Comment: Ah, I see. The character in your screenshot and the "correct" symbol look quite similar to me - maybe the font author didn't know the 100% right way to draw the symbol? I would try it with a different font to see if the problem is related to the specific font.